# Using boost::date, how do I compute "last Monday"?

Tags: c++, boost-date-time

This is how one gets "two days ago" using `boost::date`:

```
boost::gregorian::date today = boost::gregorian::day_clock::local_day();
boost::date_time::day_functor<boost::gregorian::date> day_offset(-2);
boost::gregorian::date modified = today + day_offset.get_offset(today);
```

How would one compute the date that represents "last Monday"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [previous_weekday](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#idp173086288):

```
using namespace boost::gregorian;
auto last_monday = previous_weekday(today-days(1), greg_weekday(Monday));
```

**Edit:** Added `-days(1)` to avoid returning the date given as argument, as “last Monday” would probably never mean “today” on a Monday (see the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#idp173086288)). This is also a shorter way of accomplishing your “N days ago” starting point.